# how to select exact 7 or 10 world in oracle using regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am working on below query, I am expected to select exact 7 or 10 digit values columns using regular expression, I have used express in regexp_like() function of oracle, but its not working, please help

Query :

```
select * from 
(select '1234567CELL' "a" from dual
union
select '123CaLLAsasd12' "a" from dual
union
select 'as9960488188CELLas12' "a" from dual
union
select '1234567' "a" from dual
union
select '9960488188' "a" from dual
union
select 'asdCELLqw' "a" from dual) b
where b."a" like '%CELL%' and   regexp_like(b."a",'^(\d{7}|\d{10})$');
```

**Expected output**

"1234567"

"9960488188"

as above two rows, please check

Comment: That won't work since the anchors make the pattern match at the start/end of string only. There are no word boundaries support in Oracle regex. No idea if you may use `(^|\D)(\d{7}|\d{10})($|\D)` (equal to POSIX `(^|[^[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{7}|[[:digit:]]{10})($|[^[:digit:]])`)

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the output now, can you please look again

Comment: `where  regexp_like(b."a",'^([[:digit:]]{7}|[[:digit:]]{10})$')`. If you anchor the whole regex, you cannot have `CELL` inside the string

Comment: Upped the `?` and added an `A` :) Please check.

Answer (score 0):

`^` and `$` match the start and end of a string and the value cannot contain the string `CELL` and be solely a 7- or 10-digit number. Instead you could use the regular expression `(^|\D)(\d{7}|\d{10})($|\D)` which will match either the start of the string or a not digit character `(^|\D)` then either 7- or 10- digits and then either the end of the string or a non digit character `($|\D)`.

Like this:

```
WITH data ( a ) AS (
  select '1234567CELL'          from dual union
  select '123CaLLAsasd12'       from dual union
  select 'as9960488188CELLas12' from dual union
  select '1234567'              from dual union
  select '9960488188'           from dual union
  select 'asdCELLqw'            from dual
)
SELECT a,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( a, '(^|\D)(\d{7}|\d{10})($|\D)', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) AS val
FROM   data
WHERE  a LIKE '%CELL%'
AND    REGEXP_LIKE( a, '(^|\D)(\d{7}|\d{10})($|\D)');
```

**Output**:

```
A                    VAL
-------------------- ----------
1234567CELL          1234567
as9960488188CELLas12 9960488188
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just use

```
where regexp_like(b."a",'^([[:digit:]]{7}|[[:digit:]]{10})$')
```

Since the pattern is anchored (`^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end of the string) there can't be `CELL` inside the entries you fetch, and you can remove `where b."a" like '%CELL%'` from the query.